# mongo shard config server high CPU

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We are running a sharded mongodb (v2.2) cluster with four replset shards and three shard config servers, all set up in accordance with 10gen's documentation.

We run this cluster on AWS EC2, with the three config machines as t1.micro.

We run mongos on client machines like so:

```
mongos --fork --logpath /mnt/log/mongodb.log --configdb cfg1,cfg2,cfg3
```

According to the documentation, every instance of the mongos daemon should be started with the same ordering of the config servers (e.g. cfg1, cfg2, cfg3).

Our problem is that the machine cfg1 has been getting very slow-- slowing down all of our client connections in turn.  We recently added a large number of client connections and soon after started to notice that the CPU on cfg1 was constantly maxed out at 100% while the other two machines did not have problems.

Anyone experience anything similar to this?  We have tried to upgrade cfg1 to a m1.medium but our fear is that this is just avoiding the problem and not solving it.

Comment: I think you will have more luck on serverfault. But: What is causing the high cpu usage? top of htop will give you the answer.

Comment: rather than upgrading it, have you tried just replacing it with a different instance?  EC2 definitely has lemon instances out there.